# Increase Search Performance on a Master Table by Creating a Second One? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Had trouble choosing a good title for this, so its better that i just explain it:

I have one table (T1 from now on), T1 is a master table with a bunch of columns but only one real index (Namely the ID Column), this table is really important and i must not touch or alter any of the schema/constraint/indexes/etc in it since it's modified and maintained by a Third-Party Software, so to prevent any kind of unpredictable behavior i try to avoid to modify or add anything directly in the table (So this one is mostly for consults).

Now in T1 i have 3 columns; Group1, Group2 and Group3, i noticed lately that i tend to do a good amount of queries by searching and grouping values using these 3 values as key, but since they are not indexed they hurt the query performance by a large margin and wanted to improve performance while using these columns.

Here is my question:

Is it a good idea to make a Second Table (T2), created and maintained by me, where i only include the ID(Primary Key) of T1 along with these 3 Group Columns(Indexes), to perform a join t1 with t2 and perform any filter operation on t2? (Ignoring Groups on T1 and only taking the ID)

Edit: Reading about the indexed view i found this bit:

"You can’t modify the underlying tables and columns. The view is created with the WITH SCHEMABINDING option."

Does that mean i can't modify the Groups columns in T1?

Edit2: Just went with the duplicate table (Space is cheap), and i did see a amazing increase in performance the second time i did a search using one of the groups as filter parameters. From 40-50 secs to 7-10 secs, have to see if i can reduce that a little bit more (Love how SQL can be just like a sprint, every extra second you shave can count :D)

Comment: may be you can go for an indexed view http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx

Comment: Theory is sound, how often is T1's content updated though? Building the table and it's indexes will be a significant cost if you have to do it a lot.

Comment: Indexed view is an excellent suggestion.  If that's not possible, replicating the table might also be a good option.

Comment: I'll try the indexed view, also the table is heavily modified everyday, but some records are inserted every other day, was thinking how invasive a "trigger on insert/update" would be on that table to automatically insert the record in the second table. (Leaving the First one as if)